# Accessing up and down array elements reference to a middle array element

Tags: c

I would like to know if there is a matrix of elements which is stored in a 1 dimensional array, how can I access array elements above and below the reference elements. for ex: let say there is a 3X3 matrix which has total 9 elements but im interested in the element at 
array[2][2] (i.e in 2 dimensional array). and i want to access the the array[2][1] and array[2][3] but in a 1 dimensional array. thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Good old pointer arithmetic: If the array is N by M, the first (0th) element of the second row is at offset M. In general, if you linearize your array in the C way (second index changes faster),
element a,b will be at offset a*M + b.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then:

```
int arr[9]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // You have 1D array
int (*mat)[3]=arr; //Convert it to int[][3]
mat[2][2]=5; //Change (for example) the last element to 5
```

Note that C arrays are 0-based, so you haven't `mat[2][3]`.

Comment: i cannot use the pointer matrix. i need it as bare minimum as possible cuz i got convert it into MISP assembly later

Comment: srry MIPS is bare bone assembly level language. so i need to make the c program minimalistic and simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to treat a 1 dimensional array as if it were a 2 dimensional matrix.  Then given a position in the 1 dimensional array provide the same column in the row above?  If so then try the following

```
size_t GetRowAbove(size_t index, size_t arrayLength, size_t rowLength) {
  size_t column = index / rowLength;
  size_t row = (index - column) / rowLength;
  return ((row - 1) * rowLength) + column;
}


size_t GetRowBelow(size_t index, size_t arrayLength, size_t rowLength) {
  size_t column = index / rowLength;
  size_t row = (index - column) / rowLength;
  return ((row + 1) * rowLength) + column;
}
```

Comment: yea i cannot use the functions, cuz i have to later convert this into MISP assembly. so i cannot use functions!!

Comment: and dows your function give, array element or the row below and above?

Comment: @ApekshithRamesha one gives the above and the other gives the below.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define ROW_LEN 3
int arr[9]={0,1,2,
            3,4,5,
            6,7,8}
int idx = 4;
int element = arr[idx];
int below = arr[idx + ROW_LEN];
int above = arr[idx - ROW_LEN];
```

Just take care about first and last row, since they don't have (respectively) above and below rows.